# How to create data catalog for assets in google cloud storage (objects, buckets, ..) using Google data catalog service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, metadata

Though Google Data catalog is in beta phase, currently it provides data catalog service support to BigQuery and cloud pub/sub services, not for Google cloud storage(in beta phase).

Is there any way using existing components/services we could build data catalog for  assets stored in Google cloud storage(buckets, objects, ..) and when could we possibly expect direct support for GCS in Google data catalog.

Answer (score 3):

According to **[Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/concepts/introduction-data-catalog#how_works)**

> Tagging Cloud Storage assets (for example, buckets and objects) is unavailable in the Data Catalog beta release.

Full support for Cloud Data Catalog is scheduled for the last quarter of this year, 2019. (from October-on)

Comment: Thanks @sllopis for the info, it would be much helpful if you could point the right link which carries the official release date.

Comment: Hi @Sivakumar, Google Cloud Support here! Unfortunately I cannot provide you with any links that show the release. If my answer helped you, could you mark it as an accepted answer, so it gains more visibility for other users in the community? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @sllopis, can you provide me the compatibility levels of GCS with Data catalog in beta vs public release.

Comment: Hi @Sivakumar. Actually, you can check the public Release Notes for Data Catalog for new updates [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/resources/release-notes)
As I mentioned earlier Tagging GCS assets is currently unavailable in Data Catalog for the **beta version**, which could potentially mean that it **might** be available in the next release. Again, I **cannot** assure you anything about the compatiblity levels of GCS in Data Catalog since they are **still** working on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Data Catalog became GA: [Data Catalog GA](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/data-catalog-metadata-management-now-generally-available)

And they have updated the docs for Filesets:
[Data Catalog Filesets](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/how-to/filesets)

Finally if you want to create Data Catalog assets for each of your cloud storage objects, you may use this open source script: [datacatalog-util](https://github.com/mesmacosta/datacatalog-util#82-create-datacatalog-entries-based-on-object-storage-files) which has an option to create Entries for your files.